# How to get Firebase authentication info from phone to Android wear?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, wear-os

I understand that Firebase Auth API is not available for Android Wear. However, I am working on an App where the authentication happens on the phone and some features on the wear app depend on the user authentication information on the phone. My code is a little all over the place to paste here, but if anyone has any suggestions, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a communication channel between the phone and the wearable using the [Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html). Once that's done you can sync whatever data you need as a [DataItem](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html).

An alternative might be to do the authentication on the wearable. Android Wear supports authentication using OAuth 2.0. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear.html#OAuth) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Toffer J, and I thought of doing that. But as a DataItem I can send strings and other data types but not the authentication info that I can use.

Comment: So what exactly is your authentication info? Everything can be converted into a String (and/or other primitive data types), if you really want to.

Comment: I want to be able to use it an authentication object. I have a usermanager library that takes care of authentication on phone, but my wear is not able to use the same features that phone does using authentication.

Comment: Without knowing all the details about what that authentication object looks like, I'd still ague that you could convert it into primitive data types that could be passed over to the wearable, using the Data Layer API. Then you create a new authentication object on the wearable using the transferred data (marshalling and unmarshalling just like you would normally do using either Parcelable or Serializable) . If you for some reason can't create a new authentication object consider implementing your own that only contains the data from the original object that you really need on the wearable.